# Magento > remove custom action method from layout

Tags: magento, layout, methods, action

I'm using a module that contains the action method 'SearchAutocomplete'. Could i remove this method somehow, just like with removeItem?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <block type="searchautocomplete/layout" name="search.block">
            <action method="SearchAutocomplete" ifconfig="searchautocomplete/general/enabled" />
        </block>
    </default>
</layout>
```

Right now the only solution i have is to make the changes in the xml file, which is not update-safe. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According this XML you can disable this method in module configuration. Just find configuration and in `General` section should be selector for disable this.